# How I can get references for Natural Language processing(NLP) and Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am beginner researching in NLP and Named Entity Recognition.I want to have references tor theses.

Comment: Have you tried Google Scholar or a commercial bibliographic database? This isn't a programming question. Ask a librarian.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this is quite subjective... Nonetheless, here are some references I'd suggest to start with:

History and survey:

- Grishman, R., & Sundheim, B. (1996, August). Message Understanding Conference-6: A Brief History. In COLING (Vol. 96, pp. 466-471).
- Nadeau, D., & Sekine, S. (2007). A survey of named entity recognition and classification. Lingvisticae Investigationes, 30(1), 3-26.

Task and approaches (sorted by date):

- Bikel, D. M., Schwartz, R., & Weischedel, R. M. (1999). An algorithm that learns what's in a name. Machine learning, 34(1-3), 211-231.
- Mikheev, A., Moens, M., & Grover, C. (1999, June). Named entity recognition without gazetteers. In Proceedings of the ninth conference on European chapter of the Association for Computational Linguistics (pp. 1-8). Association for Computational Linguistics.
- Miller, D., Boisen, S., Schwartz, R., Stone, R., & Weischedel, R. (2000, April). Named entity extraction from noisy input: speech and OCR. In Proceedings of the sixth conference on Applied natural language processing (pp. 316-324). Association for Computational Linguistics.
- Tjong Kim Sang, E. F., & De Meulder, F. (2003, May). Introduction to the CoNLL-2003 shared task: Language-independent named entity recognition. In Proceedings of the seventh conference on Natural language learning at HLT-NAACL 2003-Volume 4 (pp. 142-147). Association for Computational Linguistics.
- McCallum, A., & Li, W. (2003, May). Early results for named entity recognition with conditional random fields, feature induction and web-enhanced lexicons. In Proceedings of the seventh conference on Natural language learning at HLT-NAACL 2003-Volume 4 (pp. 188-191). Association for Computational Linguistics.
- Bunescu, R. C., & Pasca, M. (2006, April). Using Encyclopedic Knowledge for Named entity Disambiguation. In EACL (Vol. 6, pp. 9-16).
- Ratinov, L., & Roth, D. (2009, June). Design challenges and misconceptions in named entity recognition. In Proceedings of the Thirteenth Conference on Computational Natural Language Learning (pp. 147-155). Association for Computational Linguistics.